# getting opaquetoken to work in angular 2

Tags: angular, dependency-injection, token

Hi I can't get opaquetoken to work, did I overlooked anything?

[Plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/6MwRiXRXoc9fmEqcLDsf?p=preview)

in app.ts

```
export const SbToken = new OpaqueToken('myToken');
const testfile = 'Hello';
```

in ngModule

```
providers: [{provide:SbToken, useValue:testfile}]
```

in test.cmp

```
constructor(@Inject(SbToken) private token) {
      console.log(token)
    }
```

and i'm getting error (in punker, which uses systemJS i guess)

> (SystemJS) Error: Can't resolve all parameters for TestComponent: (?).

within my webpack Project I get similar error

```
Can't resolve all parameters for LoginPage: (NavController, SelfbitsAngular, ?).
```

Comment: Did you import the `SbToken` in `test.cmp`?

Comment: Seems I have some blue deficiency. I never see the Plunker links if they are not highlighted in some way. Sorry for that. The problem doesn't seem to be related to `OpaqueToken`. If you make it optional `(@Optional() @Inject(SbToken)` or inject `private service:TestService)` it fails the same. If you move the component to the same file as the module then it's working fine. http://plnkr.co/edit/lHIuc81COVEGv4SKGOKd?p=preview. I don't know exactly what causes the problem though.

Comment: but that kinda ruins the use of opaqueToken, doesn't it? If I can't export them for usage...

Comment: As I said the problem is not related to `OpaqueToken` at all. It seems to be some kind of import problem. As mentioned if you don't use `OpaqueToken` but inject something else by type you get the same error.

Answer (score 2):

You have a cyclic dependency between app.module and test.component.
This problem was already answer in [angular 2 OpaqueToken](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36436005)