# Angular 2 OpaqueToken vs Angular 4 InjectionToken

Tags: angular, typescript

`InjectionToken` was introduced in Angular 4 and `OpaqueToken` was marked as deprecated.

[According to the manual](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/index/InjectionToken-class.html), it is supposed to be used as

```
const anyToken = new InjectionToken('any');
```

for untyped token, and as

```
const numberToken = new InjectionToken<number>('number');
```

for typed token.

However, typed token still can be injected and used with different type when it is injected, TypeScript will be ok with this, won't it?

```
constructor(@Inject(numberToken) any, @Inject(numberToken) string: string) { ... }
```

How is `InjectionToken` supposed to benefit from TypeScript type system?

Why was `OpaqueToken` deprecated if there's no practical difference between those two?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Based on the internal usage of `InjectionToken`, for example, [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/platform-webworker/src/worker_render.ts#L97), I assume that `InjectionToken` gives you type checking benefit when getting a dependency through `injector` instance:

```
import {Component, InjectionToken, Injector} from "@angular/core";

interface AppConfig {
    name: string;
}

let APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<AppConfig>('app.config');
let appConfig: AppConfig = {name: 'Cfg'};

@Component({
    ...
    providers: [{provide: APP_CONFIG, useValue: appConfig}]
})
export class TestComponent {
    constructor(injector: Injector) {
        const config = injector.get(APP_CONFIG);
        config.s = 'd';
            ^^^^^ - Error:(14, 16) TS2339:Property 's' does not exist on type 'AppConfig'.
    }
}
```

Comment: What are exactly the benefits of using these injectionTokens instead of for example just importing constants. I understand these token can easily be mocked when testing? Other than that?? It's a lot of code for just sharing constants..

Comment: @AicoKleinOvink, it seems to be just a convention for a token related to providers in DI. If you need to use constants in your code outside of DI mechanism in Angular, just simply use constants

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com - ('app.config') Is just a placeholder. app.config can be anything? It can be like let APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<AppConfig>('types.config');??

Comment: @Hacker, yes, it's simply a text description