# Angular InjectionToken; what is 'app.config'?

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I am following the docs on how to provide, then inject a non-class instance; specifically I want to provide application wide constants.  [The docs](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection#injectiontoken) use the `InjectionToken` for this, but the explanations are very bare; consider the first part:

**app.config.ts**

```
import { InjectionToken } from '@angular/core';

export let APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<AppConfig>('app.config');
```

What's the point of the *'app.config'* string? Every example of InjectorToken that I see here uses that, but none discusses what it means or refers to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a description as can be seen from the parameter name:

```
export class InjectionToken<T> extends OpaqueToken {
  constructor(desc: string) { super(desc); }
              ^^^^

  toString(): string { return `InjectionToken ${this._desc}`; }
}
```

It can be used for debugging purposes as it's seen in the `toString` method.

It is probably modeled after [Symbol](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol) which also receives description string in the constructor:

> Parameters
>
> - description - Optional Optional, string. A description of the symbol
>     which can be used for debugging but not to access the symbol itself.

Refer to the [Angular 2 OpaqueToken vs Angular 4 InjectionToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43419050/angular-2-opaquetoken-vs-angular-4-injectiontoken/43434149#43434149) to understand why the `InjectionToken` was introduced.

Comment: I am struggling to understand. does that mean, we should keep `'app.config'` unique across the app ?

Comment: what is `app.config` you're asking about?

Comment: I mean `export let APP_CONFIG = new InjectionToken<AppConfig>('app.config');` . The param.

Comment: @ShashankVivek, it's better if you ask a separate question