# Can some explain this Injection token syntax

Tags: angular

I was looking at the angular 2 [validator file](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/4.3.3/packages/forms/src/validators.ts) . Can someone explain the syntax after "new InjectionToken"? I know its a generic type but how do you understand it?

```
new InjectionToken<Array<Validator|Function>>('NgValidators');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your token can take the following type

```typescript
Array<Validator|Function>
```

it means array of `Validator` or `Function`

where `Validator` is a class that implements `Validator` interface:

```typescript
export interface Validator {
  validate(c: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors|null;
  registerOnValidatorChange?(fn: () => void): void;
}
```

> InjectionToken gives you type checking benefit when getting a
>   dependency through injector instance

See also

- [Angular 2 OpaqueToken vs Angular 4 InjectionToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43419050/angular-2-opaquetoken-vs-angular-4-injectiontoken)