# Why error in Angular 5 as : has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'.?

Tags: angular, angular5, swagger-2.0, swagger-codegen

I have an Angular 4 application, which I am upgrading to Angular 5.

I am getting the following error.

> ERROR in src/app/application/services/generated/variables.ts(1,10):
>   error TS2305: Module
>   '"..../node_modules/@angular/core/core"'
>   has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'.

Code snippet is :

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

export const BASE_PATH = new OpaqueToken('basePath');
export const COLLECTION_FORMATS = {
    'csv': ',',
    'tsv': '   ',
    'ssv': ' ',
    'pipes': '|'
}
```

This code is been generated by [swagger editor](https://editor.swagger.io/).

Comment: It was removed. : core: OpaqueToken has been removed as it was deprecated since v4. Use InjectionToken instead. (#18971) (3c4eef8)

Comment: Some details on it's use here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43419050/angular-2-opaquetoken-vs-angular-4-injectiontoken

Comment: If you are updating from 4.x.x to 5.x.x, you should at least read the list of breaking changes in the changelog https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#500-pentagonal-donut-2017-11-01

Comment: Please see my answer.  Note: I'm a technical reviewer of the typescript language families of the codegen

Answer (score 3):

The OpaqueToken got removed. You have to use the  InjectionToken instead.
I am facing the same problem.
At the Moment the "best" solution is to replace the tokens after each code-gen build. But thats not a permanent solution.

Please contribute to this issue:
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/7324

Answer (score 3):

includes folling in the  **package.json** file

```
"@angular/flex-layout": "^2.0.0-beta.12"
```

Try deleting the node_modules folder, delete the package.json file then running the following command i hope this problem was resolved

**npm install**

please refer following link for this issue
https://github.com/angular/flex-layout/issues/494#issuecomment-343355178

Comment: Please use formatting tools to properly edit and format your answer. Also check [How to write an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Please see
https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/issues/7324#issuecomment-368548716

If you are wanting to use Angular 5, you need to use the version of swagger-codegen that supports version switching.

That this time the lowest stable version of that is 2.3.0

In that you can define (for custom config)  ngVersion to whatever version you want.  As long as that semVer is above 4.0 it will generate injection token instead of OpaqueToken.

Answer (score 1):

I had this error when I updating angular 4 to 5

I fixed this issue by change package.json file

"@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.1" to "@agm/core": "1.0.0-beta.5"

after run
npm update

Answer (score 0):

This happened when I upgraded to angular 5.2.0. I ended up having to do the following:

Edited `package.json`: Had to change my version for `@angular/compiler-cli`. In my case I had to bring it back to 5.2.0, as it somehow got to 5.2.10.

Deleted the node_modules directory.

Ran: `npm install`

Installed: `npm install @angular/flex-layout`.