# Swagger Codegen Angular 5

Tags: swagger, angular5, swagger-codegen

Is there a way to get swagger codegen to generate files for Angular 5 specifically using the newer HTTPClientModule changes? At the moment I can't even get a version of the codegen to run and the online editor won't return codegen for https://esi.tech.ccp.is/latest/swagger.json and even if it did I think it wouldn't be angular 5.

Comment: There is only up to Angular 2, you could extend swagger to work for Angular 5. This is explained here https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/How-to-add-a-generator-for-a-new-language-or-framework

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48992298/9112752

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is now solved and can be done using the -c parameter for swagger codegen and using a config file similar to the below:

```
{
  "ngVersion": "5.1"
}
```

Comment: Do you have a problem with the removed opaquetoken?  Like in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260208/why-error-in-angular-5-as-has-no-exported-member-opaquetoken

Comment: Nope. There was no problem with it at all.